# MySQL - query for duplicates of a column and return both original and duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table that I use to store some systematically chosen "serial numbers" for each product that is bought...

The problem is, a CSV was uploaded that I believe contained some duplicate "serial numbers", which means that when the application tries to modify a row, it may not be modifying the correct one.

I need to be able to query the database and get all rows that are a double of the `serial_number` column. It should look something like this:

```
ID, serial_number, meta1, meta2, meta3
3, 123456, 0, 2, 4
55, 123456, 0, 0, 0
6, 345678, 0, 1, 2
99, 345678, 0, 1, 2
```

So as you can see, I need to be able to see both the original row and the duplicate row and all of it's columns of data ... this is so I can compare them and determine what data is now inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some versions of MySQL implement `in` with a subquery very inefficiently.  A safe alternative is a join:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t join
     (select serial_number, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      group by serial_number
     ) tsum
     on tsum.serial_number = t.serial_number and cnt > 1
order by t.serial_number;
```

Another alternative is to use an `exists` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select * from t t2 where t2.serial_number = t.serial_number and t2.id <> t.id)
order by t.serial_number;
```

Both these queries (as well as the one proposed by @fthiella) are standard SQL.  Both would benefit from an index on `(serial_number, id)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  yourtable
WHERE
  serial_number IN (SELECT serial_number
                    FROM yourtable
                    GROUP BY serial_number
                    HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
ORDER BY
  serial_number, id
```

Comment: I have no idea if this query is doing anything for me ... it's just hanging. There's no a tremendous amount of data, but I would imagine that there is too much to handle?

Comment: "Error Code: 1317. Query execution was interrupted."

Comment: @dcolumbus i'd suggest you to add an index on serial_number column, it should perform much faster, or you could try gordon linoff solution, in mysql joins are often faster